# Difficulties in visual tracking in Ros-by-example book

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Rossers

I am stack over the flow, I need help plz, I don't know where I am mistaken.

I have Phantomx pincher robotic arm (with 5 dynamixel 12ax servos) connected with arbotix-m board, I am using ros indigo.

I am following this [ros-by-example tutorial](http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0016/#code2) and this [repo](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1). In order to control the first servo (id = 1) based on the motion of coloured object that should be detected by webcam. I want the servo's id 1 rotate when the object is not in the centre of x-axis. For now, I want to get one servo rotating first, then I will consider y-axis for another servo.

The [tutorial](http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0016/#code2) explains how to control the motion of the pan and tilt head servos. I am trying to consider the pan servo with my first servo.

I did the following :-

1- To get the video stream and detect the object based on colour and send the topic `/roi` which contains object's position.

```
roslaunch rbx1_vision usb_cam.launch
roslaunch rbx1_vision camshift.launch
```

2- To fire up the arbotix-m,

```
roslaunch rbx1_dynamixels arbotix.launch
```

I can also see the arm in rviz, and I can move the servo (id 1) individually `rostopic pub -1 /head_pan_joint/command std_msgs/Float64 -- 1.0`, it moves in rviz as well, it means there's real connection with the actual arm.

3- To launch the head tracking node (which should be my first servo tracking node, since I consider the `pan_head_joint` is my servo id 1). This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHJL09BTnlY&feature=youtu.be) shows the demo for the tutorial work.

```
roslaunch rbx1_dynamixels head_tracker.launch
```

I got this out put

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1508448519.996313] Waiting for joint controllers services...
```

When I run `rostopic info /head_pan_joint/command` I can see `head_pan_joint` is already ok.

```
imr@IMR-PC:~$ rostopic info /head_pan_joint/command 
Type: std_msgs/Float64

Publishers: 
 * /head_tracker (http://localhost:38610/)

Subscribers: 
 * /arbotix (http://localhost:41637/)
```

And my first servo is not moving, I do not know where I am mistaken, what to check with the third step as I mentioned above, I guess there's some thing wrong there. Please tell me !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273545/difficulties-in-visual-tracking-in-ros-by-example-book/) by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  cannot try by myself, as I have now a quite different configuration. But looking at [head_tracker code](https://github.com/pirobot/ros-by-example/blob/master/rbx_vol_1/rbx1_dynamixels/nodes/head_tracker.py#L190), looks like it tries to subscribe to a service that doesn't exists: torque_enable. Arbotix provides a service for each servo named just "enable"... looks like a reasonable bet that they are the same. So you can try to remap from torque_enable to torque.

Or given that ros-by-example code is several years old, probably better fork it so you can update those parts that had become obsolete, something that the author will probably appreciate.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1